# How to get values from JS object

Tags: javascript

I am working on the demo code below. Why am I not able to extract values from the object?

```js
var obj = {
  webSiteName: 'StackOverFlow',
  find: 'anything',
  onDays: ['sun', 'mon',
    'tue',
    'wed',
    'thu',
    'fri',
    'sat',
    {
      name: "jack",
      age: 34
    },
    {
      manyNames: ["Narayan", "Payal", "Suraj"]
    },
  ]
};


console.log(obj.onDays[2]);
console.log(obj.onDays.manyNames[1]);
```

Comment: The first one works fine, the second should be `obj.onDays[8].manyNames[1]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manyNames object is at the 8th index of the array, so therefore you need this:

```
console.log(obj.onDays[8].manyNames[1]);
```

For jack:

```
console.log(obj.onDays[7].name);
```

Or age:

```
onsole.log(obj.onDays[7].age);
```

Comment: Thanks Dream_Cap can you pleas also let me know how can I get name of `jack` as well? I mean how I can query with `name` or `age`

Answer (score 0):

You should understand the basic difference between array and object.

Whenever you deal with an Array, access by index.

```
arr[index]; // obj["onDays"][7]["name"];
```

Whenever you deal with an Object, access by the property.

```
obj[property] or obj.property // obj["find"];
```